# Flutter Bloc Listener rebuilding even though there is no state change

Tags: flutter, mobile, dart

I have an App which uses a bottom navigation bar to switch between pages. To do this, I'm using [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc).
On one of the tab pages, I render a list with some items in it. This list is built when the State changes to SchedulesLoaded(see picture).

The problem I have is that when I'm changing pages using the bottom navigation bar(Which is using a completely different Bloc) the list in the picture is being rebuilt. The Listener is actually redrawing the widget without a change in the Bloc State it's listening to. I can't get my head around why it is happening. Does anyone have a clue?

I found [this](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/368) link discussing the issue, but I got nothing useful out of it.

[image]

Comment: There is nothing in your Bloc Listener. To test out your Bloc Listener is actually executed, try to add this inside listener: (context, state) {print('bloc listener: $state')}

Comment: @FederickJonathan Should the Bloc Builder be inside the Bloc Listener instead?

Comment: @FederickJonathan The Bloc Listener does only get  called once, which is correct. But the builder is called every time I switch back to the tab, hence rebuilding the widget. How can I prevent this from happening? I would only like to build the listview once the state changes, and not redrawing it in the builder..

Comment: I am not sure how but you can try these 2 things AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and PageStorage.

Comment: AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin  doesnt work when inside a blocbuilder. you have to use the condition property in BlocBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking at this now, you can call buildWhen after building Builder to provide some condition when to build.

From docs:

An optional [buildWhen] can be implemented for more granular control over how often [BlocBuilder] rebuilds. [buildWhen] will be invoked on each [cubit] `state` change. [buildWhen] takes the previous `state` and current `state` and must return a [bool] which determines whether or not the [builder] function will be invoked.
The previous `state` will be initialized to the `state` of the [cubit] when the [BlocBuilder] is initialized.
[buildWhen] is optional and if omitted, it will default to `true`.

Example:

```
    return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: BlocBuilder<Bloc, State>(
      buildWhen: (p, c) => p.isEditing != c.isEditing,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Text(state.isEditing ? 'Edit' : 'Create');
      },
    ),
```